# google.visualiztion.ColumnChart() dont work

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my Jquery Ajax code to create a column chart using the Google API.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        //load Data Here
        var chartData = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Dashboard/GetData',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '',
            success: function (d) {
                chartData = d; 
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        }).done(function () {
            google.charts.load("current", { packages: ['corechart'] });
            drawChart(chartData);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
        });
    });`

    function drawChart(d) {
        var charData = d;
        var data = null; 
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(charData);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); 
        view.setColumns([0, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Bodily Analysis',
            legend: 'bottom',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Year',
                format: '#'
            },
            vAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 1000,
                title: 'Measurements'
            },
            chartArea: {
                left: 100,
                top: 50,
                width: '70%',
                height: '50%'
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        };

        alert(data);
        var chart = new google.visualiztion.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

        alert(data);
        var runFirstTime = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            google.visualization.events.removeListener(runFirstTime);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
```

And here is my MVC controller which return data from the database in form of JSON.

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        List<BusinessContact> Bc = new List<BusinessContact>();
        using (BusinessContContext db = new BusinessContContext())
        {
            Bc = db.BusinessContacts.OrderBy(a => a.birthDate).ToList();
        }

        var charData = new object[Bc.Count + 1];
        charData[0] = new object[]
        {
            "Birth",
            "height",
            "ChestMeasurement",
            "Weight"
        };
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var i in Bc)
        {
            j++;
            charData[j] = new object[]
            {
                Convert.ToDateTime(i.birthDate).Year,
                Convert.ToUInt32(i.height),
                Convert.ToUInt32(i.ChestMeasurement),
                Convert.ToUInt32(i.Weight)
            };
        }
        return new JsonResult{Data = charData, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

The problem I have is that the chart does not render after the JsonResult is gotten from database. I noticed that alert is not prompted right after the

```
 var chart = new google.visualiztion.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
```

Please i need help with this.

Comment: Hi @Akinnifesi Damilola , Does the alert before that line come up with what is expected? Do you see any errors in your browser console once you click ok to the first alert? What do those errors say?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @mwwallace8, i have been placing the alerts at various points and they all hit, the alert before that line does come up but the one after doesnt and as a reult i get an empty page, do i need to show u the json resuly i got from MVC.

Comment: I think you should open up developer tools in your browser (f12) and look for console errors with that line.

Comment: Ok thanks lemme give it a try

Comment: Here are the errors i got: [1] DashBoard:135 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ DashBoard:135
[2] loader.js:147 Uncaught Error: Google Charts loader.js can only be loaded once.(anonymous function) @ loader.js:147(anonymous function) @ loader.js:147
DashBoard:705              [3]Uncaught TypeError: colors.each is not a function(anonymous function) @ DashBoard:705
[4] loader.js:144 Uncaught Error: google.charts.load() cannot be called more than once.

Comment: Keeps saying google chat loader must be called one, i placed one on my layout and the other in the view cos i believed the closer they are to the script the more they work

Comment: You might start by taking the one out of your layout (if it isn't needed on other pages) and try getting just the one page to work. Once you're up and running you can try to figure out how to use in layout if you need.

Comment: if u look at my jquery, the ajax code refuses to run in the view but runs at the layout but does not produce the chart(with dynamic values), but the other chart in the view with static values wont work with the script source being on the layout ecxept its on the view...i cant understand what the problem is but do u think that is where the problem to this is or u have other ways i can create dynamic charts for my dashboard, i have been fighting with it for the past 3 months or more, pls any help will be appreciated

Comment: I wish I could help more. You do need to make sure you're only loading your scripts once and in the right order. If you do that, clear up those errors, you should be able to step through the rest of it. Good luck @Akinnifesi Damilola

Comment: I just cleared some of those errors and i got this error:                        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined at    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(charData); of my line of code

Comment: Interesting. To me that means your 'issue' is higher up in the code. Why don't you try alerting that 'd' variable at the top of the drawChart function. If the variable 'd' is undefined you need to figure out why before you can get the other pieces working.

Comment: Ok @mwwallace8, u been helpful i am still looking into it and  i will get back to u

Comment: I finally got it to work yesterday, thanks for the browser error checking idea.